# SoapUI datasource groovy script preload data

Tags: groovy, datasource, soapui, preload

I'm using SoapUI Pro, datasouce step from type groovy.

**first part of my script:**

```
def url = "http://www.xmlfiles.com/examples/plant_catalog.xml"
def slurper  = new XmlSlurper()
def content = slurper.parseText(url.toURL().text)
def allPlants = content.PLANT
```

**second part of my script:**

```
def row = testRunner.testCase.testSteps["groovyDS"].currentRow

if (row < allPlants.size()){
    result["zone"]=content.PLANT[row].ZONE
    result["light"]=content.PLANT[row].LIGHT
    result["price"]=content.PLANT[row].PRICE

}
```

Currently all script run from the beginning every row. 
I want the first part to run only once, and the second for each row

Answer (score 0):

You could warp the first part of your script in

```
if(testRunner.testCase.testSteps["groovyDS"].currentRow == 1) {
    // your script
}
```

However, this will not accomplish what you intend. On your second pass, `allPlants.size()` will error with a null poiter exception.